# SharedPreferences from different activity

Tags: android

I load from activity A the SharedPreferences in following way:

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

At activity B I want to load the SharedPreferences. Following was a NullPointerException:

```
private void LoadPreferences(){   
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    data = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "08:00") ;
}
```

If I try following, I get this compilation error: "No enclosing instance of the type A is accessible in scope"

```
private void LoadPreferences(){   
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(A.this);
    data = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "08:00") ;
}
```

How can I access the data?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` in both Activities as:

In activity A the SharedPreferences in following way:

```
 private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
        Intent sd=new Intent(this,Secongtess.class);
        startActivity(sd);
       }
```

and in Activity B get Value as:

```
 private void LoadPreferences(){   
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     String  data = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "08:00") ;
     Toast.makeText(this,data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

because as doc says:

[getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) :

> Gets a SharedPreferences instance that points to the default file that
>   is used by the preference framework in the given context.

Comment: I changed "this" to getApplicationContext(), and now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: ^ Sometime you might need to pass the SharedPreference object when you are calling the a function from Activity A to B.

Comment: It should not make a difference - your answer is confusing - the OP probably had some other problem and apparently changed something else in the code