# SharedPreferences always returning default value for custom object

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am making a simple budget tracking app. I have a Budget class that stores a few variables: the amount, duration, and initial value of budget. I only have one global Budget object inside the fragment, called "budget", and am trying to get it to save. It seems to save fine, but when I try to retrieve it, it returns the default value for some reason. Here are my methods for saving and loading. I only call getBudget() in onCreateView, and only call saveBudget in onResume() and after the budget is edited. Note the log entries.

```
public void saveBudget(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.clear();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(budget);
    Log.d("BTAG", "JSON: " + json);
    editor.putString("current budget", json);
    editor.commit();
 }

public Budget getBudget(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPref.getString("current budget", null);
    Log.d("BTAG", "gson from json: " + gson.fromJson(json, Budget.class));
    return gson.fromJson(json, Budget.class);
}
```

My log says this for my current instance of Budget:

```
D/BTAG: JSON: {"amount":35.92,"frequency":"monthly","originalAmount":35.92}
D/BTAG: gson from json: null
```

This shows that it saves without issue, but loading doesn't work. Why is getBudget() not working?

Comment: Can You Log `json` string in `getBudget()`? Maybe the problem is in converting and You receive correct string from shared preferences.

Comment: Just checked, it's showing null for json in getBudget too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be in:

> only call `saveBudget` in `onResume()`

1. You have to save the budget when the app is closing not in `onResume()`. [Check this Android Activity Lifecycle](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20191125165133/Activity-Lifecycle-in-Android.jpg).
2. Also, I think You shouldn't use hardcoded strings as key. Try to use string resources as in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#WriteSharedPreference). If You make a mistake in 'key' You will get the default value.
3. If You save budget and then load it in another activity the problem might be in getting `SharedPreferences` instance. To get `SharedPreferences` use:

```
SharedPreferences sP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

[SharedPreferences from different activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316560/sharedpreferences-from-different-activity)

You can try this, I hope this will compile:

```
public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "NAME_OF_SP";
public static final String NAME_OF_VAL = "budget";

public void saveBudget()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(budget);
    Log.d("BTAG", "JSON: " + json);
    editor.putString(NAME_OF_VAL, json);
    editor.apply();
}

public Budget getBudget()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPref.getString(NAME_OF_VAL, null);
    Log.d("BTAG", "gson from json: " + gson.fromJson(json, Budget.class));
    return gson.fromJson(json, Budget.class);
}
```

Comment: I actually had it it onResume() because the input for Budget is give in another activity. I just put it into onPause() and onDestroy() but it's still the same problem.

Comment: @drypotato so You use `saveBudget` and `getFunction` in different activities?

Comment: Nope, all saving  and getting is done in my BudgetFragment.java class. I have another class, createBudget.java, where I call BudgetFragment.budget to set variables from user input. So in the other activity I still access the static budget variable in BudgetFragment.

Comment: You can check my edit in answer and try to make `SharedPreferences` instance in another way. If it wouldn't help then I have no idea where is problem :/

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying! I'll post a solution when I figure out the issue.

Comment: Okay, last try. I added a new full code, You can try and switch it with Yours.  It should compile but I am not sure cause in my Project I didn't have `Gson` and `Budget` class. I deleted a clear method and get SP in another way.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much! Do you know why this works and my implementation didn't?

Comment: @drypotato I am so happy! I am not sure but I changed 3 things. I removed `editor.clear();`. Changed `editor.commit();` to  `editor.apply();`. And also change the way of getting `SharedPreferences` instance. You can try in Your code to change only one of these things and then You will know where exactly was the problem.